# How can I optimize mesh in gmsh? (for the intersection between entities)

Tags: python, geometry, mesh, gmsh, pymesh

I have a geometry composed of four walls, a slab, and beams.

geometry image:

[image: geometry]

I am using `gmsh` for meshing it, starting from a step file. I would like to know how to guarantee the continuity between elements in the area of the next figure. I am using Python.

Issue 2:

[image: issue]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the OpenCASCADE geometry kernel which provides some more powerful commands.

1. Start by putting `SetFactory("OpenCASCADE");` right at the beginning of your file.
2. Then use [boolean operations](http://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#Boolean-operations) to unite the different parts of your mesh. This way they will automatically stiched together. [This tutorial](https://bthierry.pages.math.cnrs.fr/tutorial/gmsh/occ/basics/#boolean-operations-cad-like-a-boss-_) by Bertrand Thierry will help you